# Counting occurrences of a foreign key in a related queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model `Visit`, which has a ForeignKey to a model `Store`. I have a filtered queryset of `Visit`s, and I need to get the count of how many `Store`s occur **at least twice** in the given queryset of `Visit`s. I know I can accomplish this with a loop, as so:

```
store_at_least_twice = {}
for visit in visit_queryset:
    # Set the value as False if this is the first time we've seen this store
    # True if we've seen it already
    store_at_least_twice[visit.store] = visit.store in store_at_least_twice.keys()
# Return count of True values
return sum(store_at_least_twice.values())
```

This gives me the result that I need, but it seems like there should be a way to do this without the overhead of iterating through every item in what could potentially be a long queryset. I have looked into using `annotate` or creating a `Store` queryset based on `visit_queryset` but haven't yet found a solution which works without a loop.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/?

Comment: Yup, I haven't found anything there that will let me get only the things that occur at least twice. That's where I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should work (or something similar depending on the related_name for the Visit to Store ForeignKey)

```
Store.objects.filter(
    visit_set__in=visit_queryset
).annotate(
    num_visits=Count('visit_set')
).filter(
    num_visits__gte=2
).count()
```

Filtering by `visit_set__in=visits` will "filter" the annotation to only count those visits

Comment: Dropped that in, updated the related_name to match what we have set, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!